# Change datasource for report viewer control programatically

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, listbox

I have 2 listboxs with selectmode set to 'multiple', the options in the listboxs are:

```
All
1
2
3

All
a
b
c
```

The comma separated list I'm creating to pass to my sql looks like this:

```
String strSegment = String.Empty;
foreach (ListItem li in lstNum.Items)
{
    if (liSegment.Selected)
    {
        strSegment += "'" + liSegment.Value + "',";
    }
}
strSegment = strSegment.Substring(0, strSegment.Length - 1);
```

My Stored Procedure looks like this:

```sql
select * 
from VIEW_TOTAL
where 
    Numbern in (@NumList) and 
    Letters in (@LetterList)
```

I'm lost about what to do when a user select 'All' or 'All','1','2','3' or doesn't select anything.
I know these are a lot of questions, I'm hoping to get some guidance or an example of how to handle passing multi select values to sql to return a dataset.

Comment: If a user selects `ALL` than that will be passed to the stored proc right? So in the proc an `if @NumList = 'ALL' clause

Comment: thank you @CSharper because it's a multiple list box can I prevent the user from selecting 'All' AND other values in the list box?  And when a user select nothing I am getting an empty string error.  This may be two separate issues ...

Comment: Yea I would look into doing this validation client side using JQuery. Capture the button click event, check if there is a selection, if there isn't display an alert and prevent the button from submitting the form. Regarding the 'ALL' and other value scenario...You could run a contains on `lstNum` and determine if 'ALL' is part of the list, if it is, insure that 'ALL' is the only value passed to the stored proc